# combine two routes to one action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-routing

I'd like to define one MapRoute which can map two different routes to one action.

I have an action to create an address:

```
public class AddressesController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Following two routes should map to the action:

**/Addresses/Create** -> To create a new address

**/Projects/3/Addresses/Create** -> To create a new address to the project with the id = 3

I tried the following MapRoute config to accomplish this, but didn't work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CreateAddress",
    url: "{projects}/{projectId}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { projects = "", projectId = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Addresses", action = "Create" },
    constraints: new { project = "(Projects)?" });
```

With this config the route `/Projects/3/Addresses/Create` is working but not `/Addresses/Create`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have both ways working in the same route.

You need to specify only the extra route, because ASP.NET MVC comes with a default one that will make sure that **/Addresses/Create** will work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

For the **/Projects/3/Addresses/Create** put this before the above route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CreateAddress",
    url: "Projects/{projectId}/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Addresses", action = "Create" });
```